# Centre of a circle that intersects two points

Tags: geometry, points

Given two points in a 2D plane, and a circle of radius r that intersects both of those points, what would be the formula to calculate the centre of that circle?

I realise there would two places the circle can be positioned. I would want the circle whose centre is encountered first in a clockwise direction when sweeping the line that joins the two points around one of those points, starting from an arbitrary angle. I guess that is the next stage in my problem, after I find an answer for the first part.

I'm hoping the whole calculation can be done without trigonometry for speed. I'm starting with integer coordinates and will end with integer coordinates, if that helps.

Comment: You will always need trigonometry to solve this problem. Given r, (x1,y1), and (x2,y2) you can have a fixed mathematical formula. But again, that formula will involve some amount of computation. Are you looking for something simpler?

Comment: If trig is needed, I guess it is needed. In the end, I am not really concerned with the absolute values of any angles, but I will be comparing relative sizes of angles (e.g. which is bigger or smaller).

Comment: Thank you all - that is the answer I have been desperately trying to find through Google, with no luck. I am trying to draw a concave polygon around geographic points, and doing that by "rolling" a circle around the edge of the point cloud. This is just one part of that solution. The only solutions to concave hulls I have found so far are either closed source tools or patent-encumbered algorithms. This is helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this but:

let:

```
q = sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)
x3 = (x1+x2)/2
y3 = (y1+y2)/2
```

first circle:

```
x = x3 + sqrt(r^2-(q/2)^2)*(y1-y2)/q
y = y3 + sqrt(r^2-(q/2)^2)*(x2-x1)/q
```

Second Circle:

```
x = x3 - sqrt(r^2-(q/2)^2)*(y1-y2)/q
y = y3 - sqrt(r^2-(q/2)^2)*(x2-x1)/q
```

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180128170023/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/53027.html)

Comment: q is the distance between the two points, and will always be 2r or less.

Answer (score 3):

A=(ax, ay)
B=(bx, by)
d=((bx-ax)^2 + (by-ay)^2)^(1/2) # distance from A to B
r=radius of your circle

if (2*r>d) there is no solution in the real world - there is a complex solution ;-)

if (2*r=d) there is one solution : the middle between A and B.

Draw a line from A to B.
Draw the perpendicular from that line at the mid-point and out to a distance D such that r=(D^2 + (d/2)^2)^(1/2). Pick left or right depending on what you want.

Answer (score 2):

This has been answered over here: [Ask Dr. Math: Finding the Center of a Circle from 2 Points and Radius](https://web.archive.org/web/20180128170023/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/53027.html)

This may also be of interest: [Gamedev.net: Circle centre given two points and radius](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/557941-circle-centre-given-two-points-and-radius/).

Comment: Dr Math's solution gives two centers. How to determine which center to use  when going in clock wise from point A to B